# How can I eliminate sheen flashing in my painted wall?

Tags: walls, flashing

I have flashing on this wall ever since I had some damages I needed to repair. I have tried to paint this wall like 4 times now restarting time and time again. I’ve tried 2 different primers and painted multiple coats and I have this textured flashing problem. The sunlight makes it look terrible. I just recently tried using joint compound over most of the wall and sanded that down to make texture even. I primed and then painted 2-3 coats. See below for my latest results. Still flashing. It’s driving me nuts. Any ideas ?[image]

Comment: What grit sandpaper are you using to sand this? Are you brushing the primer and paint on, or rolling? Are you using premium paint?